# My site stopped with this php error

Tags: php, sql, connection, out, timed

```
ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out
```

> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers
>   already sent by (output started at
>   /home/mangaat/public_html/include/config.php:7) in
>   /home/mangaat/public_html/global.php on line 18
>
> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter -
>   headers already sent (output started at
>   /home/mangaat/public_html/include/config.php:7) in
>   /home/mangaat/public_html/global.php on line 18

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in
/home/mangaat/public_html/include/functions.php on line 41
```

Comment: check function exist or not

Comment: You appear to be doing lots wrong. **Show the actual code**

Comment: paste `prepare()` function code

Comment: session_start should be at top of the page instead of line 18 before outputting anything

Comment: it was working yesterday, after i activate cloudflare this error appears

Comment: Please show you're code, we gladly help you then. [How to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Eldok Mohammed.. it means yesterday it was not displaying anything before session_start

Comment: was your issue solved?

Comment: ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/mangaat/public_html/include/functions.php on line 41

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in addition to my above comments session_start should be the very first thing

```
<?php
session_start();
//Now write rest of your code
?>
```

Comment: ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/mangaat/public_html/include/functions.php on line 41

Answer (score 0):

`session_start():` needs to ideally be the very first thing you put in your code after your opening `<?php` tag.  Certainly it needs to come before any `header` declarations or anything that renders anything to the page.

For example, this would be OK:

```
<?php
session_start():
echo 'hello';
?>
```

However, this would not:

```
<?php
echo 'hello';
session_start():
?>
```

Comment: it was working yesterday, after i activate cloudflare this error appears

Comment: Then cloudflare must be doing something that is declaring a header or rendering on-page content before your session is started

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();
```

Needs to be on top of your PHP file. Put it above all the HTML and headers and it will work.